# Database error: Running CodeIgniter program in Wampserver

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I'm trying to run a code built with PHP's framework CodeIgniter in another computer, and I've put the program folder in Wampserver's C:/wamp/www folder, but when I open the program in "localhost/program", I get the following error messages:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>       Severity: Warning
>       Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 
>       ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>       Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>       Line Number: 201
>       Backtrace:
>       File: C:\wamp64\www\program\application\controllers\Home.php
>       Line: 9
>       Function: __construct
>       File: C:\wamp64\www\program\index.php
>       Line: 315
>       Function: require_once

That's the file the error are mentioning:

**Home.php:**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {

        //print_r($this->session->userdata);

        //print_r($teste);
        $dados = array(
            'funcao' =>'index',
            'controller' => 'simplex'
            );
        if (!empty($this->session->userdata('variavel'))) {
            $this->session->unset_userdata('variavel');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('restricao');
        }
        $this->template->load('template/template', 'home/home', $dados);


    }

    public function teste()
    {

        //print_r($this->session->userdata);

        //print_r($teste);
        $dados = array(
            'funcao' =>'index',
            'controller' => 'simplex'
            );
        $this->template->load('template/template', 'home/teste', $dados);


    }


}
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP
 *
 * This content is released under the MIT License (MIT)
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014 - 2017, British Columbia Institute of Technology
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 * @package CodeIgniter
 * @author  EllisLab Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2014, EllisLab, Inc. (https://ellislab.com/)
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 - 2017, British Columbia Institute of Technology (http://bcit.ca/)
 * @license http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT  MIT License
 * @link    https://codeigniter.com
 * @since   Version 1.0.0
 * @filesource
 */

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 */
    define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        }
        else
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
        }
    break;

    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
        exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" directory.
 * Set the path if it is not in the same directory as this file.
 */
    $system_path = 'system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * directory than the default one you can set its name here. The directory
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server. If you do,
 * use an absolute (full) server path.
 * For more info please see the user guide:
 *
 * https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $application_folder = 'application';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * VIEW DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want to move the view directory out of the application
 * directory, set the path to it here. The directory can be renamed
 * and relocated anywhere on your server. If blank, it will default
 * to the standard location inside your application directory.
 * If you do move this, use an absolute (full) server path.
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $view_folder = '';


/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * DEFAULT CONTROLLER
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file.
 * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a
 * specific controller class/function here. For most applications, you
 * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those
 * special instances where you might want to override the standard
 * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation.
 *
 * IMPORTANT: If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be
 * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE
 * specific controller. Leave the function name blank if you need
 * to call functions dynamically via the URI.
 *
 * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature
 */
    // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" directory.  Leave blank
    // if your controller is not in a sub-directory within the "controllers" one
    // $routing['directory'] = '';

    // The controller class file name.  Example:  mycontroller
    // $routing['controller'] = '';

    // The controller function you wish to be called.
    // $routing['function'] = '';


/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the
 * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config
 * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file.
 * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between
 * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different
 * config values.
 *
 * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature
 */
    // $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item';



// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS.  DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Resolve the system path for increased reliability
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

    // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
    if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    else
    {
        // Ensure there's a trailing slash
        $system_path = strtr(
            rtrim($system_path, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        ).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Now that we know the path, set the main path constants
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // The name of THIS file
    define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    // Path to the system directory
    define('BASEPATH', $system_path);

    // Path to the front controller (this file) directory
    define('FCPATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    // Name of the "system" directory
    define('SYSDIR', basename(BASEPATH));

    // The path to the "application" directory
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        if (($_temp = realpath($application_folder)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $application_folder = $_temp;
        }
        else
        {
            $application_folder = strtr(
                rtrim($application_folder, '/\\'),
                '/\\',
                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            );
        }
    }
    elseif (is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $application_folder = BASEPATH.strtr(
            trim($application_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
    else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

    define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    // The path to the "views" directory
    if ( ! isset($view_folder[0]) && is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $view_folder = APPPATH.'views';
    }
    elseif (is_dir($view_folder))
    {
        if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $view_folder = $_temp;
        }
        else
        {
            $view_folder = strtr(
                rtrim($view_folder, '/\\'),
                '/\\',
                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            );
        }
    }
    elseif (is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $view_folder = APPPATH.strtr(
            trim($view_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
    else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

    define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

I'm not sure what to do, should I install something and change  the config files?

Comment: I would have to guess you have no setup your codeigniter config correctly, or maybe not set it up atall

Comment: _"Access denied"_ most likely means that you're using the wrong database credentials. Have you updated your config with the credentials to the new computers mysql server?

Comment: on the file `database.php` make sure you entered correct database credentials

Comment: First Check database login with the same credential of codeigniter config/database.

Also check your mysql services is running or not.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Comment: @Magnus is right. The issue is most likely the credentials are different on the new machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's up guys!

Watch for one of these situations:

1. Correctly edit the database connection information in the database.php file, located in "application / config / database.php
2. Define a base URL for your project at: application / config / config.php (line 27), so that it does not try to use its own computer as "localhost" instead of the remote computer. This configuration can be done in application / config / config.php. Search for $ config ["base_url"];
   Tip: Sets the IP address of the machine where your application is hosted.
3. Give permissions to the application folder (or just the logs folder) so that the application can create / write to the files. An example would be to give 755 permission to it.

Maybe this will help.